# What programming language to choose on creating a bill paying web application?

Tags: web-applications

I need to create a web-application, that people can pay all type of bills from electricity to airtime bill and many more, what programming language do i use for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose Javascript as you can do full stack development (both Frontend and Backend) with it.